# Newly built PC doesn't boot: it turns off by itself

Tags: boot, reboot

Newly built PC, built yesterday with brand-new components.

**Motherboard:** Asrock B150M-HDV
**CPU:** Intel i5-7600
**RAM:** Crucial Ballistix Sport (2x 4 GB)
**PSU:** LC-Power LC600H-12 (600 watt)
DVD burner, SSD, fan controller integrated in the case, one 120-mm fan.

I turn on the computer.
After 18 seconds, it turns itself off.
After 4 seconds, it turns itself on, and stays on indefinitely.

Nothing is ever shown on the screen (VGA). No system beep, no POST.
Checked PSU following TomsHardware's guide: nothing unusual.
Tried an old, working PSU: same problem.
Tried disconnecting *everything*: same problem.
Tried using other RAM modules: same problem.

I'm desperate... My customer will get to me tomorrow to pay and bring the PC away with him!

Comment: No beeps?  without testing the parts individually, its impossible to say what the issue is.  Have you tried another power supply?

Comment: @Keltari: yes, it's written in the question.   :-)

Comment: Sounds like the customer will not pay for this state of affairs. That means you should not pay your supplier for the broken components.

Comment: Have you tried with another motherboard?

Comment: It’s obviously not possible for us to inspect the equipment and that it was properly assembled. If it’s all new equipment then I would suggest it’s not installed properly. Start with the basics, pull everything out and start by powering the motherboard, cpu and RAM by itself. You can even try pulling the board out to make sure you don’t have standoffs in the wrong place. Once you get the basics running then add the other equipment.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
Only with the latest BIOS could the motherboard support a "Kaby Lake" processor like the i5-7600. The motherboard did have the penultimate BIOS. I updated it, temporarily using another CPU.
Now It works like a charm.